# Make CSS code change whilst viewing page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website and for Halloween I was thinking about adding a button that would change the site to halloween themed. This would be a hidden button therefore I would prefer it not be regularly in the CSS code. What i've been trying to do is make CSS code appear when you click the button via a Javascript function. Unfortunately, CSS is CSS and will just render it's code whether you hide it or not. In short I am looking for a way to change a page's layout via CSS through a function or any other method.

Comment: Toggling body tag's class may be the simplest way to do that. You can write alternative style in other css files, with every rule prefixed by the Halloween class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a separate stylesheet called halloween.css and link it to page
2. Start all the css rules with .halloween for example `.halloween h1 {background:black;color:orange}`
3. Make a button which toggles a body class, with jquery for example:

   $('#button').click(function(){
   $('body').toggleClass('halloween');
   });

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods using which you can achieve what you're trying to do. You can use the jQuery `click` function and trigger the jQuery `css` function when somebody clicks on a button.

```js
$( "#click" ).click(function() {
  $("body").css("background","black");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="click">Click Me</button>
```

Otherwise, you can use the jQuery `click` function to add a `class` to your `body` tag and then add CSS inside your stylesheet with respect to that new `body` class. For example, you can add `class="halloween"` to the `body` tag using jQuery and then have separate styles for different elements on your homepage like `.halloween h1 { //styles here } .halloween p { //styles here }`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#target").click(function () {
        $('body').addClass('halloween');
    });
});
```

```css
.halloween {
    background:red
}
.halloween #target {
    display: none;
}
.halloween p {
    color: black;
    background: white;
    padding: 30px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px 0px;
}
#halloweencontent {
    display: none;
}
.halloween #halloweencontent {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="target">Click for Halloween</button>
<p>Hello</p>
<div id="halloweencontent">Content for halloween goes here. Lorem ipsum dolor ismet. Content for halloween goes here. Lorem ipsum dolor ismet. Content for halloween goes here. Lorem ipsum dolor ismet. Content for halloween goes here. Lorem ipsum dolor ismet. Content for halloween goes here. Lorem ipsum dolor ismet. Content for halloween goes here. Lorem ipsum dolor ismet. </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it ok to using jquery, you can define a separate style like halloween.css and put all the style halloween in there. When a event click occur in a button, just swap the href attribute of link to reference the new style:

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#click").click(function() {
    $("link").attr("href","halloween.css");
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<button id="#click">Click</button>
```